# How to make a pivot table by grouping the data

Tags: r, data.table

Here is my data:

```
ID         Day          advance           nb_event
ID1         1              NA                899
ID1         1              NA                899
ID1         1              NA                899
ID1         2             0.14               899
ID1         2              NA                899
ID1         3             0.22               899
ID1         3              NA                899
ID1         3              NA                899
ID1         2              NA                899
ID1         4             -0.96              899
ID1         4              NA                899
...
ID1         30             0.74              899
ID1         30              NA               899
ID1         30              NA               899
ID1         30              NA               899
ID2         1              NA                127
ID2         1              NA                127
ID2         2             1.54               127
...
ID2         16            0.74               127
ID3         1              NA                631
ID3         2             -0.48              631
...
ID3         35            0.25               631
...
ID80459
```

explaination of the variables:

`advence`: daily advancement ;

`nb_event:` number event of each `ID`.

I want to group the `advance` and `nb_event` by the following command:

```
cut.advance <- cut(advance, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.5, -0.25, -0.1, 0, 0.02, 0.05, 0.15, 0.3, 0.5, 1, Inf), right = FALSE)

cut.nb <- cut(nb_event, breaks = c(1, 500, 1000, 5000, 15000, 20000, 50000, Inf), right = FALSE)
```

And then, how to make a pivot table which count the event for each group of `advance` according to the group of `nb_event`?

The expected result ( In the table, they are the number of relative event day):

```
                                    cut.nb
cut.advance |1-500  501-1000  1001-5000  5k-15k   15k-20k  20k-50k  more 50k
            |
More -50%   |    
-50 to -25% |
-25 to -10% |
-10 to 0%   |
Unchange    |
0 to 2%     |
2% to 5%    |   
5% to 15%   |
15% to 30%  |
30% to 50%  |
50% to 100% |
More 100%   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rws <- levels(cut.advance)
cols <- levels(cut.nb)
new_table <- matrix(0,length(rws),length(cols))
new_table[cbind(match(cut.advance, rws), match(cut.nb, cols))] <- 1
dimnames(new_table) <- list(rws, cols)
new_table
```

The `levels` argument allows us to list all of the possible cuts. We assign the `advance` cuts to `rws` to remind us to use them as our rows, `cols` for `nb_event`.

We create a new matrix with zeros.

The fun part is assigning 1's to all of the row column combinations using `cbind` and `match`. You should run those functions piece by piece to see what's happening (i.e. `match(cut.advance, rws)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But R says that "Warning message:
In cbind(match(cut.mm, rws), match(cut.nb, cols)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)". And the result is not correct. :( In my data, `length(match(cut.mm, rws))=2181`, but `length(match(cut.nb, cols))=284`, they are not the same so maybe that's way it doesn't work?

Comment: Oh, it's not the problem. I think we should make the new_table in the format of  `new_table[a,b]`, so I write the following command: `table<-cbind(match(cut.mm, rws), match(cut.nb, cols))`, `for(i in 1:nrow(table)) new_table[table[i,][1],table[i,][2]]=1+new_table[table[i,][1],table[i,][2]]`. It works but I'm sure you can improve that!

Comment: `1+new_table[table[1], table[2]]` or maybe `1+new_table[table]`

Comment: Without the `for`cycle?

Comment: No. just as you see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83347/discussion-between-velvetrock-and-pierre-lafortune).